# Cant get Toolbar to show up in Node Webkit

Tags: javascript, node-webkit

I have what should hopefully be a simple question.  According to the documentation, and tutorials that Im looking at, a basic nw.js app should have a toolbar at the top [as such](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Getting-Started-with-nw.js).  However, when I run my 'Hello World' program I have no such toolbar, it looks like this:

[image]

I also tried to explicitly turn on the toolbar in the package.json (although it sounds like it should be enabled by default), like this:

```
{
  "main": "index.html",
  "name": "example",
  "window": {
    "toolbar": true,
    "width": 800
  }
}
```

But I still get no toolbar.  What am I missing?

my version of nw.js is 0.13.0 (windows 64bit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This option was "deprecated" in 0.13:

> toolbar is deprecated and it’s always false. The traditional 
>   toolbar will NOT be supported including the reload buttons, location
>   bar and DevTools buttons. As a workaround, you can open / close
>   DevTools with F12 (Windows & Linux) or ⌘+⌥+i (Mac). And use
>   win.reload() and win.reloadDev() to simulate the reload buttons.

See: http://docs.nwjs.io/en/v0.13.0-rc2/For%20Users/Migration/From%200.12%20to%200.13/

Although the language used is 'deprecated' the option is apparently unsupported entirely.  See: https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/4274

Comment: balls.  This is true.  It should also be noted that it doesn't appear that f12 (or ctrl+shift+i) are bringing up devtools (for me anyway).